# Is there a way I can delete a wlan profile created by Group policy on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, group-policy

When I issue `netsh wlan show profiles` from command prompt on a Windows 8.1 box, it displays the following information. The account I logon this machine is an administrator role.

```
Profiles on interface Wi-Fi:
Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
    gp
User profiles
-------------
    All User Profile     : Linuxs
```

Now I want to delete the profile gp by `netsh wlan delete profile name="gp"`, and it tells me that

> You do not have sufficient privileges or the profile "gp" on interface "Wi-Fi" is a group policy profile.

I tried google out a way to delete this wlan profile, but get no luck. I'd really appreciate if there is anyone who can shed a light on this issue for me.

Answer (score 12):

Wireless connection profiles delivered by policy are stored in the `\Windows\wlansvc\Policies` folder.

To reset them, delete this folder, then restart the WLAN service.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I was using a laptop joined to domain and removed wireless networks saved.

Comment: this didn't work for me (i am w11 so maybe something has changed)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your not being accepted as the admin with the specified privileges for calling this action. It also seems as though you don't have access to changing group policy. This is something Windows won't allow unless you have direct administrative access especially with it being read only. It's like the same thing as needing root access, you would be able to change this, if your account is recognized as a administrator.

Comment: The account I used to issue commands is an administrator. What I don't know is how can I delete this profile when I logon as an administrator.

Comment: Is your windows 8 currently running under any form of active directory? And if not you'll need to access group policy and change the settings before you can actually delete the profile.

Comment: Yes. so what should I do then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh wlan delete filter denyall infrastructure
netsh wlan delete filter denyall adhoc
```